# In Cardy-Verlinde generalized uncertainty principle (GUP), how we know that the alpha is a constant of order one?

Tags: string-theory, heisenberg-uncertainty-principle

The GUP equation [1] is,
$$\Delta x_i\geq\frac{\hbar}{\Delta p_i}+\alpha^2l_p^2\frac{\Delta p_i}{\hbar},$$
where $l_p$ is the Planck length.
How do we know that $\alpha$ has a order of unity [1]? What's the proof?

Reference:

1. Setare, M. R. "Corrections to the Cardy-Verlinde formula from the generalized uncertainty principle." [*Physical Review D* **70** no. 8 (2004): 087501](https://doi.org/10.1103/PhysRevD.70.087501), [arXiv:hep-th/0410044](https://arxiv.org/abs/hep-th/0410044).

Comment: Corrections to the uncertainty principle are expected to become significant around the Planck scale. Since $l_p$ is the Planck length, $\alpha$ is expected be of order of unity. Also, GUP appears in various various models of what happens around the Planck scale, not just in the string theory, so you might consider removing the `string-theory` tag.

Comment: So, it's expected, not mandatory. Am I right? It can be 10^5. Is there no rigorous proof of α being order of unity?

Comment: You are right, there is no rigorous proof. But it can't be arbitrarily large, because there is an upper bound following from experimental data.

Comment: Could you provide me the upper bound and tell me how we calculate this bound from experimental data? Thanks in advance.

Comment: See for example [arXiv:1704.02037](https://arxiv.org/abs/1704.02037). On the page 2, $\beta_0$ plays somewhat similar role to your $\alpha^2$ and the authors say that $\beta_0 \le 10^{34}$ (roughly meaning $\alpha \le 10^{17}$) and they cite other approaches where better bounds are obtained.

Comment: For more info on upper bounds, see introduction of [arXiv:1804.05176v2](https://arxiv.org/abs/1804.05176v2). It is interesting that the paper I have mentioned in my previous comment is cited in v2, which appeared after that comment, but not in v1, which appeared before. Maybe the author has stumbled upon this question. :)